# Magento 2 getting error There is a problem with creating or binding queue

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-enterprise-2

The error says:

```
 report.ERROR: There is a problem with creating or binding queue "inventory_qty_counter_queue" and an exchange "magento". Error: [] []
[2017-01-11 07:28:02] report.ERROR: Sample Data error: Warning:
```

Comment: this is a connectivity issue with your RabbitMQ instance or cluster. I got the same while trying to connect over HTTP protocol instead of TCP.